# Advantage of *this* over event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

Is it better / faster inside an event listener to use `this` or `event.target`

I've been writing code like this (example is jQuery):

```
jQuery('input').bind('keyup', function (e) {
 var j = jQuery(e.target);
 foo(j.attr('id') , j.val() );
});
```

And I was told to replace `e.target` with `this` because it's "better". Is there really any advantage to one or the other?

I use target because it's a more general solution as it works for delegated events. I'm having trouble benchmarking because my tests get cluttered with the binding (Although, obviously, in this case the difference would be too small to matter anyway)

Comment: Using delegate, `this` returns the element matching the selector. `target` returns the element the event bubbled from.

Comment: `this` is faster in this case : http://jsperf.com/this-and-event-target

Comment: this would be slightly faster as it doesn't have to resolve `property of object`. But that is so marginal that it's not even worth discussing. If you're looking at this for performance reasons, have a look at `this.id` over `j.attr('id')` first. (Short: it really doesn't matter!)

Comment: Your jsperf is measuring the performance of *registering an event handler* rather than the performance of the event handler itself.

Comment: @Mageek Your jsperf returns opposite results if you swap the order of the tests. Does anybody have a benchmark example that actually shows which is (slightly) faster?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The one isn't better than the other, but they do different things: *this* refers to the element the event is attached to, while event.target is the element that invoked the event.

For example

```
div id=foo   
   div id=bar
```

when click is attached to foo, and bar is clicked, the event will bubble up to foo. In the event *this* will refer to *foo* and *event.target* to *bar*

In the end it depends on which element you need to handle.

There's a small example on api.jquery.com/event.target that illustrates event.target. Here's a small sample that uses that example, but which also displays *this*: http://jsbin.com/adifan/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: On delegated events the `this` still points to the same as the `event.target`. For example `$('#foo').on('click','#bar',function(e){..});`

Comment: `<p><span>foo</span></p>` having a click on `p` would cause `event.originalTarget` to point to the `span` if you click on the word `foo`.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli In your example, you bind the selector "#bar", not foo, so *this* will indeed be bar. If you bind to #foo, *this* should be foo. I've used the example from http://api.jquery.com/event.target/, and added the display of *this* to the display to illustrate the two in this sample: http://jsbin.com/adifan/edit#preview

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: That's not true. jQuery does a lot of magic there and calls your handler neither on this nor on the target, but on the selected element (second parameter), which *can* be the target.

Comment: @Me.Name, you mention "*`this` refers to the element the event is **attached** to*".. The event is attached to `#foo` but is set-up to handle events that occur on the `#bar` element..

Comment: @Bergi, i did not say otherwise.. i know jQuery normalizes the `event` argument. Just saying that on delegated events (*in jQuery*) both `this` and `event.target` point to the element we want..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: But that's not true. this points always to the selector-element (#bar), while event.target will point to the innermost element clicked on (might be a child of #bar).

Comment: @Bergi, now i got what you meant.. indeed, for even deeper elements `event.target` will target the innermost one.. not the one we want with the selector.. good point ! (*+1 all your comments.. for keeping my in-line*)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the jQuery documentation is clear about it :-)

> The target property can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when events bubble.

(Source: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

This link explains the term "event bubbling": http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html